# I have a problem in java method code which returns the division of two numbers

Tags: java, methods, try-catch, throw

In this code a division method is implemented, so i want to handle 3 cases where division is undefined using try catch and throws, but it gives me an error message that the division method must return float .
package calculator3;

//Class implements interface
public class implementation  implements calc {

```
//Add function
    public int add(int x, int y) {
        int ans1 = x + y ; 
        return ans1 ;

    }

    //Divide function
    public float divide(int x, int y) throws RuntimeException{
        try {
            if(y == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY || y == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY || y == 0 ) {
                throw new ArithmeticException("invalid_division");

            }
            else {        
                return x / y ;
            }

        }catch  (ArithmeticException invalid_division ) {
            System.out.println("invalid_division");
        }
}
}
```

Comment: `float` should already handle these permutations.  All you should have to do is catch the resulting exceptions or let them bubble up to the caller.

Comment: x and y are ints, so x/y performs integer division, not float division. You need to cast one of them to a float in order to get the correct answer. Also, you should probably use doubles, not floats, to get more accurate results.

Comment: and, if doing floating (`float` or `double`) division, be aware that there will hardly be any thrown exception (results would either be `NaN` or some `infinity`) Specification: [15.17.2. Division Operator /](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2)

Answer (score 1):

Your `divide` return type is `float`.

An int will never equal `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` or `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` because those are not in their range of possible values.

The function will not throw an error if it is caught.

Taking above 3 points:

```
//divide
public float divide(int x, int y) throws ArithmeticException{
        if (y == 0) throw new ArithmeticException("invalid_division");
        return (float)x / y; // cast x to float so a float will result
}
```

Comment: So I should make an exception only for y = 0

Answer (score 0):

Your not actually throwing the exception once catching it so the compiler will complain that your missing a return in your `divide()` method.

add:

`throw e;`

to your catch clause